# If Else Statement inside entity query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, if-statement

im trying to produce an if else statement inside entity query, i have the following code:

```
var asset = dbContext.Set<Asset>()
    .Include(x => x.Item)
    .Include(x => x.Item.ItemDetailSubCategory)
    .Include(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus)
    .Include(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.AssetCondition)
    .Include(x => x.Currency)
    .Include(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.AssetAccessories)
    .Where(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.Room.Floor.IsActive == true)
    .Where(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.Room.Floor.Building.IsActive == true)
    .Where(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.Room.IsActive == true)
    .ToList();
```

now i expect something like :

```
var asset = dbContext.Set<Asset>()
    .Include(x => x.Item)
    .Include(x => x.Item.ItemDetailSubCategory)
    .Include(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus)
    .Include(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.AssetCondition)
    .Include(x => x.Currency)
    .Include(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.AssetAccessories)

if(x.AssetCurrentStatus.AssetLocation != null)
{
    .Where(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.Room.Floor.IsActive == true)
    .Where(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.Room.Floor.Building.IsActive == true)
    .Where(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.Room.IsActive == true)
}
else
{
    .ToList()
}
```

is there any way to achieve this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, an `if` doesn't make sense because you want to apply that logic on every asset not only once. So you need to apply it to the query itself:

```
var asset = dbContext.Set<Asset>()
    .Include(....)
    .Where(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.AssetLocation == null 
            || (x.AssetCurrentStatus.Room.Floor.IsActive 
             && x.AssetCurrentStatus.Room.Floor.Building.IsActive 
             && x.AssetCurrentStatus.Room.IsActive))
    .ToList();
```

Consecutive `&&` are the same as consecutive `Where`.

Comment: this gave me an error sir saying operator && cannot be applied to operand type of bool

Comment: yeah thats true, one of my properties is a nullable bool and i did put the == true, thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```cs
var asset = dbContext.Set<Asset>()
                .Include(x => x.Item)
                .Include(x => x.Item.ItemDetailSubCategory)
                .Include(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus)
                .Include(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.AssetCondition)
                .Include(x => x.Currency)
                .Include(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.AssetAccessories)
                .Where(x => x.AssetCurrentStatus.AssetLocation != null ? 
                        x.AssetCurrentStatus.Room.Floor.IsActive == true && x.AssetCurrentStatus.Room.Floor.Building.IsActive == true && x.AssetCurrentStatus.Room.IsActive == true :
                        true).ToList();
```